# Quit decode of empty streaming http json goroutine In Go

Tags: go

I have a long-lived streaming json response that I'm processing in a goroutine as follows. I'm using a quit channel to exit the goroutine periodically. Quitting works great while data's flowing (on the next loop), however, while nothing's being streamed, decoder.Decode holds up execution waiting for the next line of json, which holds up the quit. Suggestions on how to quit gracefully?

```
quit := make(chan bool)

decoder := json.NewDecoder(response.Body) // response.Body is streaming json

go func() {
  for {
    select {

    case <-quit:
      return

    default:
      decoder.Decode(&myStruct) // this blocks when there's no data 

      process myStruct...

    }
  }
}()

... quit <- true // stop execution as needed
```

Comment: Blocking reads block. Is there a particular reason you need it to exit immediately rather than next time it reads? It consumes next to no resources while waiting on IO.

Comment: @Adrian because it could wait a really long time between reads, or even forever. In my use case I need to quit, re-configure, and re-launch on a regular basis.

Comment: It won't prevent the application from closing - when `main()` exits, the application will close no matter what else is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't interrupt a blocking read. If you want to interrupt reading of the response body, you need to cancel the http request. This will close the connection, causing the blocked `io.Reader` to return `io.EOF`.

Create a "cancellable" request using the [Request.WithContext](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.WithContext) method, and provide it with a [cancellation](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithCancel) [context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context).

Comment: Thanks @JimB The cancellation context worked perfectly. I also like how easy Go makes it to set up and use:
https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithCancel